# R: applying a function over a group

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I am looking to apply a function to a data frame and then store the results of that function in a new column in the data frame.

Here is a sample of my data frame, tradeData:

```
Login   AL  Diff
    a   1   0
    a   1   0
    a   1   0
    a   0   1
    a   0   0
    a   0   0
    a   0   0
    a   1   -1
    a   1   0
    a   0   1
    a   1   -1
    a   1   0
    a   0   1
    b   1   0
    b   0   1
    b   0   0
    b   0   0
    b   1   -1
    c   1   0
    c   1   0
    c   0   1
    c   0   0
    c   1   -1
```

Where the "Diff" column is the column I am trying to add. It just just the difference between the values row(x-1) and row(x) of tradeData, grouped by Login.

Here are some samples of what I've tried:

```
tradeData$Diff = ave(tradeData$AL,tradeData$Login,FUN = function(x) {diff(x)})
```

and

```
tradeData$Diff = as.data.frame(with(tradeData,tapply(AL,Login,FUN = diff)))
```

I've found the following question useful thus far: [R applying a function to a subset of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261159/r-applying-a-function-to-a-subset-of-a-data-frame) but I am unsure how to proceed from here, as I keep getting errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
 with(tradeData, ave(AL, Login, FUN=function(x) -1*c(0, diff(x))))
 #[1]  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 -1  0  1 -1  0  1  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1
```

Or an option using `data.table`.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" with `setDT`.  Take the difference between current and next value by group (`by=Login`).  The `shift` function (introduced in the new devel version) with `type` equals "lead" gets the next value.

```
 library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5 
 setDT(tradeData)[, Diff:=AL-shift(AL, type='lead', 
                          fill=0) , by=Login][]
```