# Pandas apply a function over groups with same size response

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196404/r-applying-a-function-over-a-group) result from R in Python.  The function I want to apply (np.diff) takes an input and returns an array of the same size.  When I try to group I get an output the size of the number of groups, not the number of rows.

Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'value':[1,2,3,4,5,1,3,2,4,3]})
```

If I apply diff to it I get close to the result I want, except at the group borders.  The (-4) value is a problem.

```
x = np.diff([df.loc[:,'value']], 1, prepend=0)[0]
df.loc[:,'delta'] = x
    sample  value   delta
0     1       1      1
1     1       2      1
2     1       3      1
3     1       4      1
4     1       5      1
5     2       1     -4
6     2       3      2
7     2       2     -1
8     2       4      2
9     2       3     -1
```

I think the answer is to use `groupby` and `apply` or `transform` but I cannot figure out the syntax.  The closest I can get is:

```
df.groupby('sample').apply(lambda df: np.diff(df['value'], 1, prepend =0 ))

x
1      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2    [1, 2, -1, 2, -1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), replace first missing values to `1` and then values to integers:

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby('sample')['value'].diff().fillna(1).astype(int)
print (df)
   sample  value  delta
0       1      1      1
1       1      2      1
2       1      3      1
3       1      4      1
4       1      5      1
5       2      1      1
6       2      3      2
7       2      2     -1
8       2      4      2
9       2      3     -1
```

Your solution is possible change by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), specify processing column after `groupby` and remove `y` column in lambda function:

```
df['delta'] = df.groupby('sample')['value'].transform(lambda x: np.diff(x, 1, prepend = 0))
```

Comment: Note for the `DataFrame.diff()`  I had to add a `.astype(int)` to coerce back to int value.